# PIG: using conditions

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following data set for a movie database:

Ratings: UserID, MovieID, Rating :: Movies: MovieID, Title :: Users: UserID, Gender, Age

Now Ive joined ratings and users. The goal is to determine each movieID rating by genders F and M together. Also to include movies which have atleast 20 ratings by F and M.

```
data = JOIN myuser BY user, myrating BY user;
grouped_users = GROUP data BY (movie,gender);
```

Now after the grouped_users, I need to filter out movie which has less than 20 ratings both genders. How can I do that?

```
grouped_users_twenty = FILTER grouped_users BY SIZE(grouped_users)>=20;
```

This is my logic. Getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [COUNT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#COUNT) and not [SIZE](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SIZE).

```
grouped_users_twenty = FOREACH grouped_users GENERATE group,COUNT(rating) as rating_count;
final = FILTER grouped_users_twenty BY rating_count >= 20;
```

Comment: I went with this : grouped_user = GROUP data BY (movie,gender);
grouped_users = FILTER grouped_user BY COUNT(data.rating)>=20;

Answer (score 0):

```
data = JOIN myuser BY user, myrating BY user;
grouped_users = foreach (GROUP data BY (movie,gender)) {
    generate
        group.movie,
        group.gender,
        SIZE(data) as user_size
    ;
};

grouped_users_twenty = FILTER grouped_users BY user_size>=20;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.